# Unity firebase storage

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-cloud-storage

i am creating a function that loads my file from local disk and uploading it onto the firebase cloud storage. The function is able to find the file in the local disk but it shows an error `firebase.storage.storageexception: could not read file` . Here is my code

```
    public void StartUpload()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Upload());
    }

    private IEnumerator Upload()
    {
        var storage = FirebaseStorage.DefaultInstance;
        var audioreference = storage.GetReference("gs://snack-stack.appspot.com");
        string local_file = "file:///" + Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "UnityTest" + "/" + "lmao.png";
        var uploadTask = audioreference.PutFileAsync(local_file);
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => uploadTask.IsCompleted);

        if (uploadTask.Exception != null)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Failed to upload because {uploadTask.Exception}");
            yield break;
        }

        var getUrltask = audioreference.GetDownloadUrlAsync();
        yield return new WaitUntil(() => getUrltask.IsCompleted);

        if (getUrltask.Exception != null)
        {
            Debug.LogError($"Failed to get a download url with {getUrltask.Exception}");
            yield break;
        }

        Debug.Log($"Downloaded from {getUrltask.Result}");
```

Comment: What do you mean that the function is able to find the file on the disk? Do you know which line above it breaks? Are you certain that you're actually pointing to a file (persistentDataPath does _not_ point to anything in your Unity Assets directory, so you would've had to put lmao.png into the persistent data path manually.

Comment: ya , lmao.png is put into the folder manually. The location of the file is located but the output shows that it could not read the file\

Comment: I think I'm bouncing between two different questions about the same thing, but have you tried using the "PutStreamAsync" call ( https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/storage/storage-reference#class_firebase_1_1_storage_1_1_storage_reference_1ad56641c76062cab644031624802c034d ) with File.OpenRead ( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.openread?view=net-5.0 ). That will push all the File I/O to .NET so you can isolate it as an issue with the game (ie: maybe a permissions thing?) or with Firebase.